# Python Zabbix API for Linux Process Monitoring

Tags: linux, api, zabbix, process-monitoring

I have installed Zabbix 4.0 for remote monitoring of Linux server. I want to monitor different processes running on Zabbix-agent in the Zabbix-server. I want to know if it is possible to retrieve different data (CPU utilization, Memory utilization, or any other related metrics) related to processes running on Zabbix-agent using any of the Python Zabbix API.

Comment: Did you did your own research? Did you read the good zabbix documentation about the [api](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/api)? What have you tried? What is the code you tried? What exactly are you have having problem with? "I want to know" - if you want to, just do it, what's stopping you?

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the basic items described in the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent), the ones you'll find useful are `proc.num`, `proc.cpu.util` and `proc.mem`.

If you need something different or more specific you'll have to create your own wrapper, for example `system.run[yourScript.sh]`.

The API has other uses as well: please open a specific question for each argument, providing both the question details and the work you've done.

Comment: `proc.num`, `proc.mem`, and `proc.cpu.util` are not available in `history.get` and `trend.get` objects of API. Aren't they command line argument for monitoring the process from terminal? Can they be also used in Python Zabbix API ?

Comment: Wait, you are mixing things up. `proc.*` are item types that you have to define on a specific host with a specific time interval. Zabbix will gather the values and store them into the history. History will become trend through the housekeeping process. The api calls are used to retrieve values of a specific items in a specific time interval.